# Notify a "remote" JComponent about a change

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, propertychangelistener

Consider a structure of JPanels as follows:

[image]

MainPanel contains two panels: AdminPanel and ReportPanel.

AdminPanel contains SetupPanel, which contains LogoPanel. 

I would like to **notify** ReportPanel about certain changes in LogoPanel. 

To do this, I have implemented a property-change *listener* in ReportsPanel. I also have in ReportsPanel a static reference to itself. 

LogoPanel uses this static reference to call the *listener*.
This solution works, but does not seem elegant to me. 

My **question**: is there a more elegant way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I crafted goes as follows: 

Created a simple **interface**:

```
    public interface Follower {

        public void changed(String property);
    }
```

and a **listener** class :

```
    public class LogoListener  {

        /**
         * A static reference to this.
         */
        private static LogoListener listener;

        /**
         * Represents the objects to be notified by the listener.
         */
        private static List<Follower> followers;

        /**
         * Create a simple listener to be used by one "notifying"
         * object, and "followers" objects.
         *
         */
        private LogoListener() {
            followers = new ArrayList<Follower>();
            listener = this;
        }

        /**
         * Method to be used by the "notifying" object, to
         * notify followers.
         */
        public void notifyFollowers() {

            for(Follower follower : followers){
                follower.changed("Logo changed");
            }

            System.out.println("Logo changed");

        }

        /**
         * Get the listener instance, or create one if it does not exist.
         *
         * @return the listener
         *              
         */
        public static LogoListener getListener() {

            if(listener == null) {
                listener = new LogoListener();
            }
            return listener;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param follower
         *       <br>Not null.
         * @throws
         *      <br>IllegalArgumentException if <code>follower</code> is   null.
         */
         public void addFollower(Follower follower) {

            if(follower == null ) {
                throw new
                    IllegalArgumentException("Follower should not be null");
            }

            followers.add(follower);
        }

    }
```

**Reports panel** (the "follower" or listening object) implements Follower interface, which simply means override changed(String message) method:

```
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see listener.Follower#changed(java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public void changed(String msg ) {
            //respond to change goes here 
            System.out.println(msg);

        }
```

and register as a follower by :

```
            LogoListener.getListener()
                        .addFollower(this);
```

**Logo panel** notifies a change by:

```
        LogoListener listener = LogoListener.getListener();
        listener.notifyFollowers();
```

Commnets and feedback is most welcome.